# Returning value of promise is diffrent when I use it outside function and cant really get why

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have 2 js files. I'm trying to call in `index.js` result of a promise from function `all()` in `listings.js`. And it logs expected object with data as result if I console.log inside `async function all()`, all is good BUT once I try `return` value to `index.j`s and store it in variable and then console this variable it shows that inside of it some promise with status panding... What? Is there is something I don't know? 
 Once again I wrapped it into `await` to get result and it's what I expected inside that function, but once I return value from func it looses into promise.
 Question: how do I properly return value to variable?

index.js

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import {all} from './listings';

let result = all();
console.log(result); //returns promise, why???
```

listings.js

```
export async function all() {
    let res = await makeRequest('http://sellbuyschool42.com/listings');
    console.log(res); //return expected object with data, all is GOOD
    return res;
}

function makeRequest($url, options= {})
{
    return fetch($url).then((responce) => {
        if(responce.status != 200)
        {
            return responce.text().then((text) => {
                throw new Error(text);
            })
        }
        return responce.json();
    })
}
```

Comment: It's an `async function`, so it returns a promise. You cannot return the value synchronously. Just make your `console.log` statement wait for the result with `.then()` or `await`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that **an async function returns a promise**. It does not return the result of that promise. Instead, you must resolve that promise to get the value.

In your index.js file, when you call the `all()` function you need to either use `then()` or `await` to get the actual result of the async function.

```
let result = await all();
console.log(result);
```

OR

```
all().then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
}
```

Remember that in the first solution (if you use await), you'll need to make that parent function async as well.